# Find anchor with title that contains text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to find an anchor whose title contains a string

This is what I have:

```
<a href="https://some.url/article1" title="Permalink to: &quot;Some Article 1&quot;">Some Article 1</a>
<a href="https://some.url/article2" title="Permalink to: &quot;Some Article 2&quot;">Some Article 2</a>
```

I need to catch these anchors.  All I know is that their title contains the word Permalink.  The rest of the title varies.

I tried this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@title[contains(text(), "Permalink")]]')
```

I expect to get the elements, but I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you are expecting you could use the css selector instead, like this:

> a[title*='Permalink']

and then try this out as :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*='Permalink']")
```

Even you can get a list of WebElements using same selector and perform your required actions as per.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following xpath should work

```
//a[contains(@title,'Permalink')]
```